# Pandas dataframe merge on rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, dataset

I have a data frame named df and it looks like below, I want to convert the 5 rows into a single row that is merge them. But 
`df=df.groupby(df.index).sum()` seems to not work for the first two columns, Any Ideas why and how do I correct it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [GroupBy.sum()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) method will ignore all not numeric dtypes.

Demo:

```
In [137]: df
Out[137]:
   a  b  c    s       date
0  9  2  6  __6 2001-01-01
1  0  1  2  __2 2001-01-02
2  6  7  5  __5 2001-01-03
3  6  8  5  __5 2001-01-04
4  0  3  8  __8 2001-01-05

In [138]: df.groupby('a').sum()
Out[138]:
    b   c
a
0   4  10
6  15  10
9   2   6

In [139]: df.dtypes
Out[139]:
a                int32
b                int32
c                int32
s               object
date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: But, all my columns are of type float64

Comment: @JayanthKumar, i've never saw float values like `BL` before ;) (What about `EVENT_ID` column)?

Comment: I Actually meant the columns in the new merged dataframe(which excludes EVENT_ID column). See the `ACTVOFT` column. In the merged dataframe it prints out 7 but indeed it should be 2 right? My question was why is it so, the dtype of that column is float64

Comment: @JayanthKumar, it should be 2 for the __first five__ rows. What is the output of: `print(df.ix[df.PATNO==14281, 'ACTVOFT'].sum())`

Comment: its 7 & Sorry for the trouble the `df.head()` command did not display the full dataframe that's why I was a bit confused. The command works fine. Thanks !!

Comment: What if one of my column has dtype=object and I want to do the similar operation merge on rows?

Comment: @JayanthKumar, i think i have answered your original question. If you have another one - please open a new quesiton